# Mysql Workbench: Command out of sync issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running stored procedures, listed stored procedure with particular date line wise, but after 2 to 3 lines execution it gives me command out of sync error then I have to select and run SP again. 
e.g

```
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-21','2016-12-23');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-23','2016-12-25');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-25','2016-12-27');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-27','2016-12-29');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-29','2016-12-31');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2016-12-31','2017-01-02');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-02','2017-01-04');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-04','2017-01-06');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-06','2017-01-08');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-08','2017-01-10');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-10','2017-01-12');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-12','2017-01-14');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-14','2017-01-16');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-16','2017-01-18');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-18','2017-01-20');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-20','2017-01-22');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-22','2017-01-24');
CALL `map`.`Sp_FRE_MM_loop`('CC','2017-01-24','2017-01-26');
```

Comment: Workbench is notorously poorly written software.  Have you verified that you are running the latest version?

Comment: this error is occuring because you have an open cursor somewhere